# Jasper Server Asynchronous report execution not working with multiple server instances

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I'm implementing the Asynchronous report execution with Jaspersoft and follow the [docs](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/running-report-asynchronously). I have 2 jasper server instances and traffic is manage through a load balancer and the load balancer supports only round-robin policy.

According to documentation, reportExecutions API (http://:/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/reportExecutions) successfully returns a requestId. But report polling service (http://:/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/reportExecutions/requestID/status/) always gives 404 resource.not.found error.

When server running on a single instance, all APIs are working properly.

I'm using the TIBCO jasperserver 7.1.0 Enterprise edition.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Have you ever found a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1052476/resourcenotfound-error-when-trying-look-reportexecution-details-requestid), the issue is in cookies. Getting "Cookie" header from response of the reportExecutions API and adding it to polling request will solve the issue.